# Read multiple CSV files from website (URL) using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, integration, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I have a SQL Server table with many different URL's in it, and each URL is pointing to a particular CSV file of same format. No credentials needed to use the URL to download the CSV file it pointing to.

Is there anyway to read these CSV files from that URL using SSIS?

I am  trying to read all CSV data to proper SQL Server tables.

I tried with a Flat File Connection but that is failing when attempt to loop. Also tried with an HTTP Connection, but no win.

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use a Transact-SQL task and put the list of files into an object variable. Then use a For Each Loop Container to iterate through that object variable.

Comment: I made it work using Object variable with Execute SQL Task and then downloaded files using For Each ADO Enumerator within a loop. Used the script task to download file (Please note that we can't read it directly, but need to download a physical copy of csv)

This article was also helpful
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/benjones/using-a-c-script-task-in-ssis-to-download-a-file-over-http

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up an object variable called URLS
2. Execute SQL task mapped to URLS
3. Foreach (ADO Object on URLS)
4. set up string variable called url
5. set foreach variable to url
6. Add a script task in foreach
7. Add url as read
8. Add this script

   ```
   System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
   wc.DownloadFile(Dts.Variables["url"].Value, @"C:\[where you want to go].csv");
   ```
9. Add a dataflow to process the downloaded file.